# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de se trabalhar com FireDac

Tags: banco-de-dados, firedac

Tem-se falado muito bem do `fireDac` mas quais as ***Vantagens*** e ***Desvantagens*** de usá-lo?
Quais bancos de dados mais se adéquam a essa tecnologia?

Answer (score 0):

**Desvantagens**: Acredito que a desvantagens você terá se precisar mudar toda a estrutura de conexão de um software legado por exemplo ADO, DBExpress para Firedac, que terá mudança de properiedades e médotos. Tirando isso não vejo nenhuma outra, pois você só terá benefícios.

Visão geral do FIredac segundo a Embarcadeiro:
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Overview_(FireDAC)

**Vantagens**

*Algumas vantágens explícitas*:

FireDAC é fruto de 10 anos de experiência no desenvolvimento de aplicativos de banco de dados do mundo real.

O FireDAC permite que o desenvolvedor se concentre no desenvolvimento do aplicativo, não nas complexidades da interação com o banco de dados.

O FireDAC fornece um conjunto moderno de componentes ricos em recursos para atender a todos os principais ambientes RDBMS.

FireDAC usa um conjunto de componentes para endereçar todos os tipos de RDBMS suportados.

FireDAC reduz o Custo Total de Propriedade ao fornecer: Menor custo inicial, em comparação com bibliotecas caras separadas. Menos tempo necessário para aprender e se familiarizar com as poderosas bibliotecas exclusivas. Design e desenvolvimento de aplicativos diretos ao direcionar diferentes bancos de dados.

Minhas opnião (Pessoal) das principais Vantagens:

Dinamismo em criar alias/variáveis de objetos do banco [Macro](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC))

Exemplo:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM &TabName';
FDQuery1.MacroByName('TabName').AsRaw := 'Orders';
FDQuery1.Open;

{IF Oracle} SELECT * FROM OracleTab {fi}
{IF MSSQL} SELECT * FROM MSSQLTab {fi}
```

Linhas afetadas em Update, delete ou insert [Rows Affected](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomCommand.RowsAffected)

Exemplo:

```
  ADCommand1.Execute;
  if ADCommand1.RowsAffected = 1 then
// Command executed
```

E muitos outros.